# associate array key value pair with seperator

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

```
$user  = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($user);
```

The output  I got was:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => US101
            [FirstName] => Ramesh
            [MobileNo] => 3125627127
            [City] => Bombay
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => US102
            [FirstName] => Ravindar
            [MobileNo] => 45624152627
            [City] => Culcatta
        )
)
```

the output I need is:

```
Array
(
    [US101] => US101 | Ramesh | 3125627127 | Bombay
    [US102] => US102 | Ravindar | 45624152627 | Culcatta
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$formatted = [];
foreach($user as $v)
{
  $formatted[$v['ID']] = implode(' | ', $v);
}

print_r($formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `CONCAT_WS` like  below

```
select CONCAT_WS('|',ID,FirstName,MobileNo,City) from table_name;
```

then output will be concat column values

Answer (score 0):

```
$userModified = array_map(function($item) {
    return [
        $item['id'] => implode($item, '|')
    ];
}, $user);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!